# Can I send email of two differnt message to two different recipient using Mandrill at the same time

Tags: php, laravel-5, mandrill

In php, I am sending email to users while registering.

Now I want to send one email to admin as well at the same time, But message will be different, like **`"New registration"`** to admin and **`"Thank you for registering"`** to user.

Is this possible ? I am using **`Mandrill`**.

I know about sending email to multiple recipient but the same message not the different.

Comment: Just send first msg for user. and second msg for admin. I didn't see any problems!

Comment: Also i guess, first and second message. Mandrill will sending in one time.

Answer (score 1):

As per Mandrill API documentation, you can have multiple recipients for a message, but only 1 email/subject.

The easiest solution would be to just make 2 API calls with different message content (1 for the user, one for the admin).

But if you were dead-set on making a single API call, you would need to utilize the message customization feature that allows you to define merge_tags for recipients.

The body/subject would each become a merge tag, and you define the values of merge tags on a per-recipient basis. So you would define a different merge value for the user than for the admin for both the subject & body of the message.

Then Mandrill would substitute the correct subject/body message as it sent.